# Proxy Alias between two servers

Tags: django, apache

Is that possible to make proxy server between two servers only in apache?

I have server1, e.g. http://server1.com

And this server communicate by ajax with temporary server2, e.g. http://server2.com

And on the server2 I have a small Django app which communicate with server3.

e.g.

```
def myview(request):
    #take data from requst
    #make some extra operations
    #make another request with requests to server3
    #if data from server 3 comes, return it as a response
```

Can I change this django app by apache proxy?

If I send request from server1 to http://server2/smt it must be redirect to http://server3/smt and server3 make backend operations and return it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simply:

```
ProxyPass "/foo" "http://foo.example.com/bar"
```

in your apache conifg